# Setting the background using a handler in android

Tags: android, handler

I want to change the background when you click a button, but only for a short period of time. I'm using a Handler

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    setContentView(relativeLayout);

                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r,2000);
        }
    });
```

}   }

However, now it takes two seconds for the background to change instead of changing it for two seconds. Anyone an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used `handler.postDelayed`. So the code inside the runnable will run after 2 seconds. To make it work as you want, one way is to take you code which sets the background, outside the runnable. Then inside the runnable you can again use `setContentView` to set it to the previous one.

Comment: Hold on, now when I use setContentView inside the handler to set it back to normal I can't use the other buttons anymore. How can I set it back to normal?

Comment: Where are your "other buttons" ?

Comment: The rest of my buttons are all on the main screen spread around, what I want to achieve is, you click a button (background is an image) and then the image becomes the whole screen for 2 seconds. And then you click another button and so on

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this.

Use a StateListDrawable instead. *Its exactly for this purpose*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_pressed"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_normal" />
</selector>
```

Set this as the background for your Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
private boolean mState;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mState) {
                return;
            }
            mstate = true;
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newcolor); //this color will last for 2sec

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                 mState=false;
                 relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oldcolor);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r,2000);
        }
    });
```